# JUnit Testing Java EE web-service endpoint methods

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, junit

How is a Java EE web-service endpoint method tested using JUnit?

I'm using *Spring* and *MyBatis* frameworks and the standard *Maven* directory structure in *Eclipse*. I know I could simply test each method by creating a JUnit test-case for it. But, I'm wondering how I can make use of the **@WebService, @WebMethod, @WebResult tags** for the testing.

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.ws.BrowserService", name = "BrowserService", targetNamespace = "http://abc.def.com")
public interface BrowserService {

    /**
     * Runs the provided SQL query and returns the result.
     * @param queryText is the SQL query text.
     * @return The query result is returned in the form of List<Object>.
     */
    @WebMethod
    @WebResult(name = "Object")
    public List<Object> runQuery(
            @WebParam(name = "QueryText") String queryText);

}
```

### Edit

#### Implementation

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://abc.def.com", portName = "BrowserPort", serviceName = "BrowserService")
public class BrowserServiceImpl implements BrowserService {

    @Autowired
    private QueryMapper queryMapper;

    public List<Object> runQuery(String queryText) {
        List<Object> queryResult= new ArrayList<Object>();
        queryResult = queryMapper.runQuery(queryText);
        return queryResult;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, what I was looking for in fact was *Integration Testing*.